# ABP version update using NuGet package manager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, upgrade, asp.net-boilerplate

I have been tasked with creating a screen on an existing website that uses ASP.NET Boilerplate, to track the changes of entities and who made the changes.

When I go into NuGet package manager to update ABP version, which was at version 0.9.5, I can only get the version to update up to ABP version 2.3.0.

But that version does not have what I am looking for, which is the ability to enable Entity History in `PreInitialize()`:

```cs
Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabled = false;
```

I would like to update to the latest version of ABP, which is version 3.5.0.

But when I update, I get error:

> Could not install package 'Abp 3.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have installed all dependencies needed for latest version of ABP:

```
.NETStandard 2.0
Castle.Core (>= 4.2.1)
Castle.LoggingFacility (>= 4.1.0)
JetBrains.Annotations (>= 11.1.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory (>= 2.0.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options (>= 2.0.0)
Newtonsoft.Json (>= 11.0.1)
.AsyncEx.Context (>= 1.1.0)
Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination (>= 1.0.2)
System.Collections.Immutable (>= 1.4.0)
System.ComponentModel.Annotations (>= 4.4.1)
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager (>= 4.4.1)
System.Data.Common (>= 4.3.0)
System.Linq.Dynamic.Core (>= 1.0.8.2)
System.Linq.Queryable (>= 4.3.0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters (>= 4.3.0)
System.Security.Claims (>= 4.3.0)
System.Threading (>= 4.3.0)
System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument (>= 4.3.0)
TimeZoneConverter (>= 2.3.0)
```

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just upgrade 3 major versions from v0.x to v3.x as there are several breaking changes.
Upgrading from ABP v0.9.5 means you're probably upgrading from [v1.5.2 of the MVC5 template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/releases/tag/v1.5.2).

It's already non-trivial to [upgrade from v2.x to v3.x](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/compare/v2.1.1...v3.0.0).
**You're better off downloading the new template**: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Template

More importantly, you will need to port changes as there is no [EF6 support for Entity History](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3022) yet.
However, the bulk of the Entity History feature is in the main Abp package. You can check [#2835](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/2835).